# Install Yii2 extension manually without using Composer

Tags: php, widget, composer-php, yii2

I want to install [Select 2 extension](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2) widget manually with Yii2 Framework without using composer.

I done the following steps but it's not working.

**1)** Added `yii2-widget-select2` to `vendor/yii-soft`

**2)** Added following code in my `yii-soft/extensions.php`:

```
'yiisoft/yii2-widget-select2' => array(
    'name' => 'yiisoft/yii2-widget-select2',
    'version' => '2.0.3.0',
    'alias' =>
    array(
        '@yii/kartik' => $vendorDir . '/yiisoft/yii2-widget-select2',
    ),
),
```

**3)** Added display in view form:

```
use kartik\select2\Select2;

<?php echo Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'state_2',
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],
]); ?>
```

And It shows the following error:

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException. Class
>   'kartik\select2\Select2' not found

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's highly recommended to use composer instead.

But if you want to do it manually:

**1)** Download archive of needed version from Github.

**2)** Open `composer.json`.

**3)** Find PSR-4 autoload section and remember it, in your case: `kartik/select2`.

**4)** Extract files to corresponding folder in `vendor`: `vendor/kartik/select2` (not `yiisoft`!).

**5)** Add to `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`:

```
'kartik\\select2\\' => array($vendorDir . '/kartik/select2'),
```

**6)** Add to `vendor/yiisoft/extensions.php`:

```
'kartik/select2' => array (
    'name' => 'kartik/select2',
    'version' => '2',
    'alias' => array (
        '@kartik/select2' => $vendorDir . '/kartik/select2',
    ),
),
```

**samdark**, one of the core contributors has the article in russian about it on his official blog [here](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/kak-postavit-rasshchirenie-na-yii-2.0-bez-composer). It's basically brief translated version.

As you can see it's quite a lot of work to do. Multiply it by number of extensions and it becomes pain.

Seriously, use `composer`. If the hoster doesn't support it, find another one.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Why make it so hard on yourself? Worst case scenario you can just add the composer.phar to your own files and run it like that.

Comment: what about the dependencies how are you going to manage it? installing locally and then uploading via ftp is lot more easier, quicker

Answer (score 2):

You can use [yii2-workbench](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-workbench/) package. It designed for easy intergrate package without composer. It support composer autoload and bootstrap

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: looks like its your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

It is subrepository `.GIT` , delete `.git` from `vendor\kartik-v\yii2-widget-select2` and `git rm --cached yii2-widget-select2`

Stash, Commit,Push.