# Configure Module Yii2 without Composer

Tags: php, module, yii2

Reference:

[Install Yii2 extension manually without using Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480329/install-yii2-extension-manually-without-using-composer)

http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/kak-postavit-rasshchirenie-na-yii-2.0-bez-composer

I want to configure http://demos.krajee.com/grid module in my Yii2 project. The steps given in their documentation asking me to install this extension through composer. But I want to configure it manually without using composer.

I've followed steps given in [this](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/kak-postavit-rasshchirenie-na-yii-2.0-bez-composer) document to configure extension without using composer and it worked for me

Same way are there any steps to configure module manually without using any composer.

Comment: see this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480329/install-yii2-extension-manually-without-using-composer

Comment: I followed those steps but not working