# How to install Jquery UI in YII2?

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, composer-php

I work on YII project (advanced) and want to use [JUI Extension for Yii 2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui)
I've put **"yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0"** line to my composer.json file and run **composer install**.
After that I've tried to use widget:

```
<?php

use yii\jui\Sortable;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel common\models\SearchSomeModel */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

echo Sortable::widget([
    'items' => [
        'Item 1',
        ['content' => 'Item2'],
        [
            'content' => 'Item3',
            'options' => ['tag' => 'li'],
        ],
    ],
    'options' => ['tag' => 'ul'],
    'itemOptions' => ['tag' => 'li'],
    'clientOptions' => ['cursor' => 'move'],
]); ?>
```

But there was an error:

> **The file or directory to be published does not exist: /path/advanced/vendor/bower/jquery-ui**

Then I've read a recomendation on github to remove composer.lock and /vendor folder and made **composer install** again.

After that any page of my app gives error:

> **The file or directory to be published does not exist: /path/advanced/vendor/bower/jquery/dist**

What am I doing wrong?

[enter link description here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui)

Comment: Preferred way to install extension is with composer but if you want it to install manually then make sure you follow  [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480329/install-yii2-extension-manually-without-using-composer).

Comment: As I've write, I used composer, didn't try to install extention manually.

Comment: try reinstalling using: `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui`

Comment: Tried to do this. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have outdated fxp plugin.

Run:

```
composer self-update
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"
cd /path/to/advanced/application
composer update
```