# Yii widgets not working

Tags: php, yii, widget

i am new in yii2 i am learning about widget but it's not working on me so guys could you help me to find what mistake i have done?

This is the widget which i am using =>  [yii datepicker widget](https://github.com/mrlco/yii2-jalali-datepicker)

and MY code

```
 <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use mrlco\datepicker\Datepicker;

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $model backend\modules\settings\models\Companies */
    /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
    ?>

<div class="companies-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_start_date')->widget(
        Datepicker::className(), [
            'inline' => false,
            'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
            'clientOptions' => [
                'format' => 'YYYY/MM/DD'
            ]
    ]);?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'company_status')->dropDownList([ 'active' => 'Active', 'inactive' => 'Inactive', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

it says

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>
> The file or directory to be published does not exist:
>   D:\server\htdocs\munivihar\advanced/vendor\bower/persian-date/dist

[it show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTXoU.png)

So could you guys help me to find my mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of this error is :

1. Try to install this widget using Composer.It will place all folder at there positions.
   2.If doing it manually then try to place the files as on there place otherwise it will not work it happened with me also.

Recommend way is use composer other wise  use [Install Yii2 extension manually without using Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480329/install-yii2-extension-manually-without-using-composer)

Comment: ThankU frn but i am using it from composer but also i can't use it i have try many widget but also same problem so i don't know what to do now :(